# Where is Stack Exchange hosted now?

Tags: discussion, web-hosting

Where is Stack Exchange/ Stack Overflow hosted now?

I found a few posts from a few years ago and am not sure if they are current.

Comment: Which posts? Hard to say if they're current or not without a link. ;) The short version is that we have two data centers - one in Colorado, one in New Jersey. The latter is currently our primary.

Comment: @AdamLear do you mind sharing the name of the company in NJ? it was a post on the SE blog

Comment: I don't recall it off the top of my head. I can ask around when I'm back in the office next week, though. But out of curiosity, why do you ask?

Comment: looking for a reputable hosting company to host my server

Comment: @AdamLear You don't have the Oregon datacenter anymore?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog We might still technically have one, I'm not 100% sure. But either way, nothing runs out of it or is set up to run out of it like it used to be.

Comment: Pretty sure I saw a tweet about the last servers being removed on Nick Craver's twitter.

Comment: ah https://twitter.com/SuperDalgas/status/947998519998033920 citation found! Was a retweet and damn does Nick Tweet a lot.

Comment: @rene The answer to that question does not explain where the servers are.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog yes it does under the heading *Host three datacenters:*. When I was editing my answer to add the other datacenters Google returned me that specific post so I stopped editing and dupe hammered it. No need to replicate that stuff in a dozen places. And if you feel that the dupe is not correct then please down vote my answer because it has to be incorrect as well in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The New Jersey Datacenter is hosted at [QTS](https://www.qtsdatacenters.com/) as they are mentioned in the blog [How we upgrade a live data center](https://blog.serverfault.com/2015/03/05/how-we-upgrade-a-live-data-center/) authored by [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver).

It says in that blog

> This is where we have to give a shout out to [our data center QTS](https://www.qtsdatacenters.com/).

showing the appreciation for that company.

As far as I know they didn't switch providers after that, at least not for the one located near NJ.

Comment: QTS! That's the one. Yeah, there haven't been any switches since that post. It's still accurate.